# arduino flashing LED on pressed button c# application

Tags: c#, arduino

I connected arduino with c# application by bluetooth connecton, On digital pins 2 and 4 are connected two LEDs
When i press a button on c# application via bluetooth the command comes to arudino and "digital write" (LED HIGH) is executed and it glows without stopping. My question is how to improve arduino code so that the LED light glows only when the button is pressed, or when we stop pressing the button with mouse it stops glowing.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
int LED=2;
int LED=4;

void setup()
{

    pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
} 
void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
  int command = Serial.read();
 {
   if(command == 'LED1_ON')
   {
     digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
   }
     else  if(command == 'LED2_ON')
   {
    digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Provide 2 commands per led: `LED_ON` and `LED_OFF`. When you press button (`MouseDown`?) - send `LED_ON`, when release (`MouseUp`?) - send `LED_OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

sorry my bad English. I try to help you ;)  First i suggest to avoid declaring your variables
in loop() function.

```
 int command = Serial.read();
```

It is good habit to declare this at the beginning of your source code (where is your leds declared). But the question. I guess, your serial link is aviable, when you press the button isnt it? So than you can turn off your leds when it is not available:

```
 if (Serial.available() > 0)
 { ....}
 else { /* turn off youre leds */ }
```